# Add custom GridView to WinUI 3 C# app (could not use Page.Resources or Window.Resources)

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, resources, winui-3

I am working on a **WinUI 3 C# project** for the first time. This is my code XAML code so far and it works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Window
    x:Class="Greek_Television.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Greek_Television"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Greek Television">

    <Window.SystemBackdrop>
        <MicaBackdrop Kind="BaseAlt"/>
    </Window.SystemBackdrop>


    <StackPanel>

        <Grid x:Name="AppTitleBar"  
      Height="48">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="LeftPaddingColumn" Width="0"/>
                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="IconColumn" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="TitleColumn" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="LeftDragColumn" Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="SearchColumn" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="RightDragColumn" Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="RightPaddingColumn" Width="0"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image x:Name="TitleBarIcon" Source="/Images/WindowIcon.png"
           Grid.Column="1"
           Width="16" Height="16"
           Margin="8,0,0,0"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="TitleTextBlock" 
               Text="Greek Television" 
               Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"
               Grid.Column="2"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Margin="4,0,0,0"/>
            <AutoSuggestBox Grid.Column="4" QueryIcon="Find"
                    PlaceholderText="Αναζήτηση"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Width="300" Margin="4,0"/>
        </Grid>

        <Pivot>
            <PivotItem Header="Όλα τα κανάλια">
                <!--This is where I want to add the GridView-->
            </PivotItem>
            <PivotItem Header="Ελληνικά">
                <!--This is where I want to add the GridView-->
            </PivotItem>
            <PivotItem Header="Ξένα">
                <!--This is where I want to add the GridView-->
            </PivotItem>
            <PivotItem Header="Αγαπημένα">
                <!--This is where I want to add the GridView-->
            </PivotItem>
        </Pivot>

    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

Inside each Pivot tab, I want to add a **custom GridView**, like the one suggested by *WinUI 3 Gallery* app from Microsoft Store. This is the code as provided exactly by the Gallery app:

```
<!-- The GridView used for this sample is shown below, with all of the necessary added properties. -->
<GridView
    x:Name="ContentGridView"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ImageTextTemplate}"
    IsItemClickEnabled="False"
    CanDragItems="False"
    AllowDrop="True"
    CanReorderItems="True"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    SelectionChanged="ContentGridView_SelectionChanged"
    ItemClick="ContentGridView_ItemClick"
    FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>

<!-- ContentGridView_SelectionChanged and ContentGridView_ItemClick are functions defined in the code-behind
to handle the events of when a selection changes on the GridView and when an item is clicked. -->

<!-- The data template bound to this GridView's ItemTemplate property is based on which one you
select from the options on the right. The currently selected DataTemplate is: -->

<!-- ImageTextTemplate: -->
<DataTemplate x: Key = 'ImageTextTemplate' x: DataType = 'local1:CustomDataObject'>
    <Grid AutomationProperties.Name = '{x:Bind Title}' Width = '280'>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width = 'Auto'/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width = '*'/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Source = '{x:Bind ImageLocation}' Height = '100' Stretch = 'Fill' VerticalAlignment = 'Top'/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column = '1' Margin = '8,0,0,8'>
            <TextBlock Text = '{x:Bind Title}' Style = '{ThemeResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}' Margin = '0,0,0,8'/>
            <StackPanel Orientation = 'Horizontal'>
                <TextBlock Text = '{x:Bind Views}' Style = '{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}'/>
                    <TextBlock Text = ' Views ' Style = '{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}'/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation = 'Horizontal'>
                    <TextBlock Text = '{x:Bind Likes}' Style = '{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}'/> 
                    <TextBlock Text = ' Likes' Style = '{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}'/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
     </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

I do not know how to add this into my code. I have tried using *<Page.Resources>* or *<Window.Resources>*, but VS underlines these and throws errors if I try to use them (I am not sure how to use them correctly anyway).

Any help appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the resources directly to the window itself, you can add resources to the root element of it:

```
stackPanelRoot.Resources.Add(...);
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window
    x:Class="Greek_Television.MainWindow"
    ...>


    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanelRoot">
```

Of course you can also add the resources to the root element directly in the XAML markup:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
         <GridView x:Key="...">
```

Comment: I am sorry. I do not understand. How to do this?

Comment: You give the `StackPanel` in your window an `x:Name` like I demonstrated in the answer. And then you add resources to the `StackPanel` instead of adding it to the window. So instead of `this.Resources.Add`, you call `this.stackPanelRoot.Resources.Add`.

Comment: But this is not XAML code, is it? stackPanelRoot.Resources.Add(...);

Comment: No. But you can add resources to the `StackPanel` in the XAML markup as well. See my edit.

Comment: I see. Within the StackPanel.Resourcesm should I add the whole XAML code from the WinUI 3 Gallery app, or only the <DataTemplate> and the top part inside the pivot?

Comment: You should add whatever resources you want such as for example a `DataTemplate`.

Comment: I wrote the <DataTemplate> part as StackPanel.Resources. Now, how can I use the GridView inside each Pivot tab? I mean, how do I call it?

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. You should not ask more than one question per thread and I believe the resources errors that you were getting have been sorted out, right?

Comment: Νο. Resources seem to have been added, but I do not know how to use/call them. The ultimate question is how to do this CustomGridView work.

Comment: That's not how your question reads.

Comment: My question title says "Add custom GridView to WinUI 3 C# app"

Comment: No, it says "Add custom GridView to WinUI 3 C# app (could not use Page.Resources or Window.Resources)" indicating that your issue is how to be able to resources.

Comment: Yes, indeed that was a part of my question. But it is not complete! Anyway, I do not find any meaning in going on like this. I don't mean to be rude or ungrateful. Your answer is indeed too helpful, I just need a little bit more to solve the puzzle.